# Run managed application with embedded netframework dependencies

Tags: .net

As we already know, C# compiled application can't run without the netframework installed on the machine.

I'm wondering if it's possible to add the required files from the netframework which a basic c# application needs and force it to use the needed files from integrated resources when it is being executed.

Comment: That was a somewhat popular product in the early days of .NET 1.x, Remotesoft's Salamander .NET linker for example.  Expensive and has not held up well, pretty difficult to compete with a product that's available for free.  Everybody stopped bothering with it, .NET is just part of Windows today.

Answer (score 0):

No, that isn't possible.

However, virtually all Windows machines have .NET installed however. .NET2/3.0 came with Windows Vista and later, and Win8 has .NET4 by default.